# how to get data from two different php classes files into one file..?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating registration form in which I creates two three different classes file first is database file in which data is fetched from database second is display file which html template and last one is controller file which get data from both of that files.
Now my problem is that how merge both display and database classes file in file through controller class file..

Comment: Iam not really sure what you mean, but just include/require them?
http://php.net/manual/de/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a perfect use for the PHP `include()` function.

If you have two php files, `foo.php` and `bar.php`, if you add `include 'bar.php';` at the top of `foo.php` they will essentially be concatenated when the PHP parser is reading through your code.

Note that they are concatenated in order, so wherever you `include()` a file in your PHP, that's where the code will be parsed; keep that in mind for variable scoping and order-of-operation.